# How to extend the width of the div when hover?

Tags: html, css

### Details

- I want to extend the width of the div when I hover on them
- I have my menu laid out like this

[image]

and here is how I style my menu

```
/*Sticky*/

.sticky-AS{

    font-size: 15px !important;
    color: orange !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    background-color : transparent !important;


}
.sticky-EU{

    font-size: 15px !important;
    color: #50c0de !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    background-color : transparent !important;


}
.sticky-NA{

    font-size: 15px !important;
    color: red !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    background-color : transparent !important;


}
.sticky-OC{

    font-size: 15px !important;
    color: #428bca !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    background-color : transparent !important;


}
.sticky-SA{

    font-size: 15px !important;
    color: #5cb85c !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    background-color : transparent !important;


}
.sticky-AF{

    font-size: 15px !important;
    color: #6E6E6E !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    background-color : transparent !important;


}
```

### What I've tried

- Note : I tried to force set the width to 700 px, but It didn't work.
- But the `font-weight: bold;` work when I hovered.
- I was wondering maybe someone can shed the light on this.

Here is how I style my hover

```
*Sticky*/
    .sticky-AS:hover{
        font-size: 15px !important;
        font-weight: bold;
        width: 700px !important;
        color: orange !important;
        text-decoration: none !important;
        background-color : transparent !important;
    }
    .sticky-EU:hover{
        font-size: 15px !important;
        font-weight: bold;
        width: 700px !important;
        color: #50c0de !important;
        text-decoration: none !important;
        background-color : transparent !important;
    }
    .sticky-NA:hover{
        font-size: 15px !important;
        font-weight: bold;
        width: 700px !important;
        color: red !important;
        text-decoration: none !important;
        background-color : transparent !important;
    }
    .sticky-OC:hover{
        font-size: 15px !important;
        font-weight: bold;
        width: 700px !important;
        color: #428bca !important;
        text-decoration: none !important;
        background-color : transparent !important;
    }
    .sticky-SA:hover{
        font-size: 15px !important;
        font-weight: bold;
        width: 700px !important;
        color: #5cb85c !important;
        text-decoration: none !important;
        background-color : transparent !important;
    }
    .sticky-AF:hover{
        font-size: 15px !important;
        font-weight: bold;
        width: 700px !important;
        color: #6E6E6E !important;
        text-decoration: none !important;
        background-color : transparent !important;
    }
```

For someone curious, and want to see more, here is my `PHP` code

```
<ul id="sticky" class="sticklr">

                <?php 

                    foreach(array_unique(array_values($continent)) as $continent_id){

                        if($continent_id == 1 ){ $continent_name = "Europe" ; $continent_code = "EU" ;  
                        }elseif ($continent_id == 2 ){ $continent_name = "Asia" ; $continent_code = "AS" ;    
                        }elseif ($continent_id == 3 ){ $continent_name = "North America" ; $continent_code = "NA" ;    
                        }elseif ($continent_id == 4 ){ $continent_name = "Oceania" ; $continent_code = "OC" ;   
                        }elseif ($continent_id == 5 ){ $continent_name = "South America" ; $continent_code = "SA" ;   
                        }else{  $continent_name = "Africa" ; $continent_code = "AF" ; }  

                        ?>

                        <li>
                            <a href="#<?php echo $continent_name ?>" class="sticky-<?php echo $continent_code ?>">
                                <?php echo $continent_name ?>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                <?php }?>
            </ul>
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fxfcLv5b/)

Comment: @ShikharBhardwaj : give me 2 mn. I am on it.

Comment: Over use of the '!important' tag is bad practice and should only be used when absolutely necessary to achieve the desired result (but can be an indication that there is a better way of doing things).

Comment: I would also suggest creating one base set of CSS style rules to define those styles common to all <li> elements, then simply specify the unique and over-riding styles in the individual element's rules.

Comment: @Chris: I'm in a situation that I need overide the original css that come with the plug-in called [sticklr](http://codecanyon.net/item/sticklr-sticky-side-panel-css3-jquery-plugin/full_screen_preview/302039), I tried everything I could, and `!important` seem to work. If you have any better suggestion for me on this, please let me know.

Comment: @ShikharBhardwaj : here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fxfcLv5b/)

Comment: Depending on the plug-in system's implementation and your particular dependency on any other styles it introduces it may be possible to remove the plug-in's style-sheet all together and just use your own custom style rules?!

Comment: -- or -- use a 'heavier' CSS selector to over-ride the plug-in style rules (damn comment edit timed out!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initially, define width for all the a tag inside the Li.

Ex: `#sticky li  a{  width:200px;  border:solid 2px red; display:block }`

try to run bellow snippet

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>

    <style type="text/css">
        .sticky-AS { font-size: 15px !important; color: orange !important; text-decoration: none !important; background-color: transparent !important; }
        .sticky-EU { font-size: 15px !important; color: #50c0de !important; text-decoration: none !important; background-color: transparent !important; }
        .sticky-NA { font-size: 15px !important; color: red !important; text-decoration: none !important; background-color: transparent !important; }
        .sticky-OC { font-size: 15px !important; color: #428bca !important; text-decoration: none !important; background-color: transparent !important; }
        .sticky-SA { font-size: 15px !important; color: #5cb85c !important; text-decoration: none !important; background-color: transparent !important; }
        .sticky-AF { font-size: 15px !important; color: #6E6E6E !important; text-decoration: none !important; background-color: transparent !important; }




        .sticky-AS:hover { font-size: 15px !important; font-weight: bold; width: 700px !important; color: orange !important; text-decoration: none !important; background-color: transparent !important; }
        .sticky-EU:hover { font-size: 15px !important; font-weight: bold; width: 700px !important; color: #50c0de !important; text-decoration: none !important; background-color: transparent !important; }
        .sticky-NA:hover { font-size: 15px !important; font-weight: bold; width: 700px !important; color: red !important; text-decoration: none !important; background-color: transparent !important; }
        .sticky-OC:hover { font-size: 15px !important; font-weight: bold; width: 700px !important; color: #428bca !important; text-decoration: none !important; background-color: transparent !important; }
        .sticky-SA:hover { font-size: 15px !important; font-weight: bold; width: 700px !important; color: #5cb85c !important; text-decoration: none !important; background-color: transparent !important; }
        .sticky-AF:hover { font-size: 15px !important; font-weight: bold; width: 700px !important; color: #6E6E6E !important; text-decoration: none !important; background-color: transparent !important; }

        #sticky li a { width: 200px; border: solid 2px red; display: block; }
    </style>

</head>
<body>

    <div style="width:200x; background-color:yellow">
        <ul id="sticky" class="sticklr">


            <li>
                <a href="#<?php echo $continent_name ?>" class="sticky-AS">
                    INDIA
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#<?php echo $continent_name ?>" class="sticky-EU">
                    USA
                </a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#<?php echo $continent_name ?>" class="sticky-NA">
                    CANADA
                </a>
            </li>

        </ul>

    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing: Try adding a border line to see what is happening. Second: have your height set to `auto`.

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of...

```
#sticky {
    height:
    width:
    overflow:
    etc.
}

#sticky li {
    background-color: transparent;
    font-size: 15px; /* could set this on the <ul> and <li>'s will inherit */
    text-decoration: none;
}
.sticky-AS { color: orange; }
.sticky-EU{ color: #50c0de; }
.sticky-NA{ color: red; }
.sticky-OC{ color: #428bca; }
.sticky-SA{ color: #5cb85c; }
.sticky-AF{ color: #6E6E6E; }

#sticky li:hover { width: increased-amount }
```

Please note that since the `<li>` elements are children of the `<ul>` the parent element would automatically increase in width as well (to accommodate the growing child). This would likely result in other elements being pushed around (and the background colour of the menu expanding).

Fix the background simply by setting the background colour of the `<ul>` to transparent, none or the same as it's parent element, then set the background colour in the rules that apply to all `<li>`s -- this way whe none expands you will only see the background of the child element grow with it.

To fix the parent `<ul>` element from growing too would likely require use of the overflow property on the parent as well as (possibly) z-indexes and/or position attributes such as 'absolute' (with the necessary offset's to make it's position appear correctly) for the children.

Answer (score 0):

You were trying to change the width of the anchor elements which are inherently inline. Use `display:block` to let them be rendered as block level elements. Then you can change the width. Fiddle edited for the 1st element : http://jsfiddle.net/92u4cute/2/

Answer (score 0):

Not usre if i understand correct but you add in li elements following css rules:

```
ul li:hover {
    background: silver;
}

ul li {
    width: 100px;
}
```

```css
 /*Sticky*/
 .sticky-AS {
   font-size: 15px !important;
   color: orange !important;
   text-decoration: none !important;
   background-color: transparent !important;
 }
 .sticky-EU {
   font-size: 15px !important;
   color: #50c0de !important;
   text-decoration: none !important;
   background-color: transparent !important;
 }
 .sticky-NA {
   font-size: 15px !important;
   color: red !important;
   text-decoration: none !important;
   background-color: transparent !important;
 }
 .sticky-OC {
   font-size: 15px !important;
   color: #428bca !important;
   text-decoration: none !important;
   background-color: transparent !important;
 }
 .sticky-SA {
   font-size: 15px !important;
   color: #5cb85c !important;
   text-decoration: none !important;
   background-color: transparent !important;
 }
 .sticky-AF {
   font-size: 15px !important;
   color: #6E6E6E !important;
   text-decoration: none !important;
   background-color: transparent !important;
 }
 /*Sticky*/
 .sticky-AS:hover {
   font-size: 15px !important;
   font-weight: bold;
   width: 700px !important;
   color: orange !important;
   text-decoration: none !important;
   background-color: transparent !important;
 }
 .sticky-EU:hover {
   font-size: 15px !important;
   font-weight: bold;
   width: 700px !important;
   color: #50c0de !important;
   text-decoration: none !important;
   background-color: transparent !important;
 }
 .sticky-NA:hover {
   font-size: 15px !important;
   font-weight: bold;
   width: 700px !important;
   color: red !important;
   text-decoration: none !important;
   background-color: transparent !important;
 }
 .sticky-OC:hover {
   font-size: 15px !important;
   font-weight: bold;
   width: 700px !important;
   color: #428bca !important;
   text-decoration: none !important;
   background-color: transparent !important;
 }
 .sticky-SA:hover {
   font-size: 15px !important;
   font-weight: bold;
   width: 700px !important;
   color: #5cb85c !important;
   text-decoration: none !important;
   background-color: transparent !important;
 }
 .sticky-AF:hover {
   font-size: 15px !important;
   font-weight: bold;
   width: 700px !important;
   color: #6E6E6E !important;
   text-decoration: none !important;
   background-color: transparent !important;
 }
 ul li:hover {
   background: silver;
 }
 ul li {
   width: 100px;
 }
```

```html
<ul id="sticky" class="sticklr">
  <li> <a href="#Europe" class="sticky-EU">Europe</a>

  </li>
  <li> <a href="#Asia" class="sticky-AS">Asia</a>

  </li>
  <li> <a href="#North America" class="sticky-NA">
        North America       </a>

  </li>
  <li> <a href="#Oceania" class="sticky-OC">
        Oceania       </a>

  </li>
  <li> <a href="#South America" class="sticky-SA">
        South America       </a>

  </li>
  <li> <a href="#Africa" class="sticky-AF">
        Africa       </a>

  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is some things i suggest you change to your design (i would comment but i need 50 rep...) :

1- you should apply a class to your li tags, and it should be this class' width that is changed by the css.

2- by making sure that your CSS is after the one that you are trying to override and !important shouldn't be necessary, unless it use !important, which is bad...

3- most of the stuff you're defining in the sticky tags are the same, centralize them using class="sticky sticky-US" and define the repeated stuff in .sticky . It will make it simple to know what is what

in my example, border and background is added for ease of demonstration

CSS:

```
    /*Sticky*/
    .sticky {
        font-size: 15px !important;
        border: 1px solid red;
        width: 60px;
        background-color : grey;

    }
.sticky a {
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
    .sticky-AS{
        color: orange !important;       
    }
    .sticky-EU{
        color: #50c0de !important;      
    }

    /*Sticky*/
    .sticky:hover {
        width:200px;
    font-size: 15px !important;
        font-weight: bold;

    }
```

html :

```
<ul id="sticky" class="sticklr">


                        <li class="sticky">
                            <a href="#Europe" class="sticky-EU">
                                Europe                          </a>
                        </li>

                        <li class="sticky">
                            <a href="#Asia" class="sticky-AS">
                                Asia                            </a>
                        </li>
                            </ul>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fxfcLv5b/13/)

Answer (score 0):

In order to actually change the width of the container, probably a `<div>` which I added below, you'll need to set it to `display: inline-block;` which tells it to assume the width of its children. Moving onto the actual list just set the width of the `<li>` to something default and on `li:hover` increase the width of the `<li>`. Check the snipped below!

A working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/hz67xywg/1/

```css
.sticklr li {
  width: 125px;
}

..

.sticklr li:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 135px;
}

.something {
  display: inline-block;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="something">
  
  <ul id="sticky" class="sticklr">
    <li>
      <a href="#"></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  
</div>
```